# Is there a problem in ZPP not yet in P?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, randomness

Primality was a nice problem that was in ZPP but was not known to be in P. Is there a (preferably simple to state) problem of which we can prove that it is in ZPP but we do not know whether it is in P or not?

I know ZPP=EXP might hold and so on, I want a problem surely in ZPP that is not surely in P.

Comment: Surely the last sentence might be confusing since one interpretation would be that you are asking for their separation whereas you are probably looking for conjectured candidates. Recalling that the number of problems conjectured to be between P and NP are so small there are probably no problem conjectured to be in ZPP-P.

Comment: In addition, as far as I recall, it is a common to conjecture that ZPP=P.

Comment: If instead of ZPP you ask about RP, polynomial identity testing would be an answer.

Comment: @Kaveh: It is also a common conjecture that BPP=P, yet we have other interesting questions on this site such as problems known to be in BPP but not known to be in RP union coRP (http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11425/problem-in-bpp-but-not-known-to-be-in-rp-or-co-rp). Also, although the number of problems conjectured to be truly NP-intermediate is a couple of orders of magnitudes smaller than the number known to be in P or NP-complete, I wouldn't characterize it as "so small": http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc.

Comment: I wonder if there are generalizations of the primality problem itself for which the ZPP algorithm (Adleman–Huang) works, but AKS does not.

Comment: For the (nearly-)linear time analog of your question, I believe that there are many algorithms on permutation groups that are known to be in $\mathsf{ZPTIME}[\tilde{O}(n)]$ (that is, Las Vegas nearly-linear time, where the "nearly-" means up to poly-logarithmic factors) that are not known to be in $\mathsf{DTIME}[\tilde{O}(n)]$. See, e.g., the book "Permutation Group Algorithms" by A. Seress.

Comment: @Josh, my point: we shouldn't expect finding problems that are conjectured to be in ZPP-P as long as we conjecture ZPP=P (i.e. as it seems to me that is what domotorp is looking for in the last sentence of the question).

Comment: If you allow search problems, how about finding a prime between $n$ and $2n$?

Comment: @Kaveh: This logic does not work, as Josh pointed out most people also conjecture BPP=P.

Comment: @Sasho: Yes, for search problems that would be a good example but I really want what I asked for - my main goal is to give an example for students.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to answer your question, but the 'Bellagio' or 'pseudo-deterministic' algorithms of Gat-Goldwasser are relevant.  These are randomized algorithms to solve an NP search problem, that w.h.p. return some fixed value (but may occasionally give another value or fail to solve the search problem at all).   http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2011/136/

Comment: @Kaveh: Until we have a proof, I think it's healthy, when believing a conjecture such as ZPP=P, to keep in mind potential counterexamples. Both because the conjecture might turn out to be false, and because any proof of the conjecture must somehow take care of all the potential counterexamples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Problem:

Input: $\;\;$ a tuple that parses as $\:\langle \hspace{.04 in}p,\hspace{-0.03 in}y,\hspace{-0.03 in}i\hspace{.02 in}\rangle$

Output:

if $p$ is prime and $y$ is a [quadratic residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $p$, $\;$ then the $\hspace{.02 in}i\hspace{.03 in}$th$\hspace{.01 in}$ bit of the

non-negative integer $x$ that satisfies $\;\;\; x^{\hspace{.02 in}2} \equiv y \; \pmod p\;\;\;$ and $\;\; 2\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}x \: \leq \: p \;\;$,

else 0

According to [the wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_or_prime_power_modulus), that problem is in ZPP but is not known to be in P.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I was wondering why did you format it in this odd way? It doesn't *really* matter but I find it distracting.

Comment: I tried to put things that go together closer together. $\:$

Comment: I guess primes and commas do not go together then :)

Comment: It's inequalities and [commas that are not part of the inequality] that do not go together. $\hspace{.52 in}$

Comment: Embarrassing, I used to know this problem...

Comment: @RickyDemer even your comments are formatted in a odd way.

Comment: @Arul : ​ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_or_prime_power_modulus ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: A generalization of this problem is factorization of univariate polynomials over finite fields (one has to take care to define the output in such a way that it is unique, so that it makes sense to take its bitgraph).