# Are there any examples of problems in ZPP not yet in P?

Tags: complexity-classes, randomness

Is there a problem of which we can prove that it is in ZPP but we don’t yet know whether it’s in P or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a problem in ZPP not yet in P?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19921/is-there-a-problem-in-zpp-not-yet-in-p)

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/19921/5038

Comment: Perhaps, but these things change over time, that question was many years ago

Comment: AFAIK, the situation hasn't changed. And if it does, hopefully someone will post the answer to my question ;)

Comment: 1. Please don't re-ask the question.  That is not considered appropriate.  You can place a bounty on the original question, or upvote it.  2. That question already has an answer, so your question is answered there.