# Are there any problems in $\mathsf{BPP}$ that are known to be $\mathsf{RP}$-hard or $\mathsf{coRP}$-hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, big-picture, randomness

It's suspected that probabilistic complexity classes such as $\mathsf{RP}$ or $\mathsf{BPP}$ don't have complete problems. Of course, their promise counterparts have complete problems, but I am not asking about promise problems. So, I have relaxed the restriction of *completeness*.

Comment: I doubt there are natural such problems known, just because we know so few natural problems in BPP \ (RP union coRP) at all (see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/11425/129). But can one build such a problem unconditionally (even if "unnatural")? Interesting Q.

Answer (score 5):

It would be a *very* interesting result if one were able to present a language in BPP that is hard for RP (equivalently, for co-RP) under poly-time Turing reducibility (aka Cook reducibility).  I'm quite sure that no such language is known (natural or artificial).  If one can present such a set, then this would yield an enumeration of bounded-error probabilistic machines (BPP machines) that captures all of RP; this would be quite interesting, and I'm sure that no such enumeration is known.

However, note that many (perhaps most?) complexity theoreticians think that BPP = P, and thus the Circuit Value Problem is very likely hard for BPP under AC^0 reductions.